# lighten the background colour from another class

Tags: css, colors, background

Can we use lighten, Darken CSS attributes without colour value?

I have a class with the background colour
Ex:

```
.master{
      background-color:green;
}
```

---

```
<div class="master">Master</div>
```

I have to lighten the background of the "Div" **using a different CSS** class. How can I do that?

**Note:**

1. I have a few themes and predefined background colours so I have to use those colours and have a shade of it using a different class
2. Opacity is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please add your code into snippet, so someone has quickly fixed your issue. Have a nice day!!

Comment: Can you use SCSS ?

Comment: @Arkellys I'm using LESS in my project

Comment: @RaashidA. Okay, have you tried to use the `lighten()` function ? That the only thing I can think of right know.

Comment: @Arkellys Yes that doesn't help my problem :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider a pseudo element to create another layer and inherit the `background-color` then you can apply filter without any issue:

```css
.master{
      background-color:green;
}
.master2{
      background-color:red;
}

.light,
.dark{
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}
.light:before,
.dark:before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background-color:inherit;
  filter:brightness(200%);
}
.dark:before {
  filter:brightness(50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="master light">Master</div>
<div class="master2 light">Master</div>
<div class="master dark">Master</div>
<div class="master2 dark">Master</div>
```

Comment: Thank you this helped me to sort my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) CSS property to tweak the brightness as follows:

```css
.master {
  background-color: green;
}

.lighten {
  filter: brightness(150%);
}

.darken {
  filter: brightness(50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="master">Master</div>
<div class="master lighten">Master lighten</div>
<div class="master darken">Master darken</div>
```

Comment: Filter applied for the whole div on top of the layer, its mean filtering applied for content as well like opacity. I need to reduce the background colour only.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is quite easy to add a different class so that you can lighten the background of your div element. Try this example,

```
.master-light{
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5); /*where 0.5 stands for 50% opacity*/
}
```

Comment: When you have 0 values it brings the black colour in, in my case, I can't have a colour value in second class. I just need to lighten the background colour which applied through another class.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you, I think this is the only way to achieve your goal.
As you can see both the images were same, no filter is applied to the content.

```css
.master{
color:#fff;
position:absolute;
top:10px; 
left:10px;
}

.mmaster{
-webkit-filter: brightness(200%);
 background:green;  
 position:relative; 
 padding:80px 0;
 }
```

```html
<div class="mmaster"></div>
<div class="master"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/bgdesert.jpg" alt="desert">Desert</div>
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/bgdesert.jpg">
```

Comment: The filter doesn't meet my requirement its filter whole content inside the div I only need to reduce the background colour to lighten or darken.