# Lighten RGB with pure CSS

Tags: html, css, sass, brightness

Using **pure CSS** how can I lighten an RGB like: `rgb(255, 0, 0)`

SASS's `lighten` mixin works well: `lighten(rgb(255, 0, 0), 25%)` however it doesn't support CSS variables like this: `lighten(var(--redColor), 25%)`

I need to use CSS variables because you can change CSS variables on the fly after the page has loaded.

#### Things I've tried

1. `opacity: 0.75` - Opacity makes the background bleed into the color which I don't want.
2. `filter: brightness(` - Filters affect the whole element but I just want to lighten specific colors.
3. `hsl(0, 100%, 50%)` - HSL looks promising though I need a way to convert RGB to HSL in order to lighten the RGB.

Ideally I hope to have a SASS mixin that does some CSS to lighten whatever color's passed into it.

Comment: I think color manipulation is not yet supported in CSS3, but it is coming up in the CSS Color Module Level 4: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-4/

Comment: you want this to be applied to a background? there is a lot of way if it's the case

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51781919/8620333 / https://stackoverflow.com/a/65297702/8620333 / https://stackoverflow.com/a/55330103/8620333

Comment: @TemaniAfif I need this to work for text color as well so things like `filter` and `background-image` won't work.

Comment: There’s a useful article on why use HSL instead of RGB here [link] https://elad.medium.com/why-css-hsl-colors-are-better-83b1e0b6eead The great thing there is that you can use CSS variables as each of the components and lightness makes sense which it sort of doesn’t in RGB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible.

**However**

Lightening colors is very easy with `hsl` so if you store the `hsl` color along with the RGB like this:

```css
:root {
  --redColor: 142,  49,  42;
  --redColor_h: 4;
  --redColor_s: 54%;
  --redColor_l: 36%;
}
```

Then you can lighten the color with this SASS mixin:

```css
@function lighten($shadeCode, $amount) {
  @return hsl(var(--#{$shadeCode}_h), var(--#{$shadeCode}_s), calc(#{var(--#{$shadeCode}_l)} + #{$amount}));
}
```

And use it like this:

```css
background-color: lighten('redColor', 25%);
```

And boom you got lighter colors.

Comment: What about darken?

Comment: @eddy It'd be the same function, except you'd minus `#{$amount}` instead of adding it.